# I want to change the command I gave in the bin in package,json when using inquirer

Tags: node.js, inquirer, inquirerjs

This is the relevant my package.json file.I want to change this 'ruvw' into 'start'.

```
  "bin": {
    "ruvw": "./bin/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ethers": "^5.5.2",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.6",
    "link": "^2.1.0",
    "ora": "^5.4.1",
    "yargs": "^17.7.2"
  }
}
```

I am using inquirer.How to change it.

I tried to change it to start and do 'npm install inquirer' again. But it didnt work.